# HTML and JavaScript and Json = How and when to encode in which order?

Tags: javascript, html, json, security

my process looks as following:

```
1.) Server: Encode the content as HTML (=using StringEscapeUtils from apache commons)
2.) Server: Encode the content as JavaScript (=using StringEscapeUtils from apache commons)

3.) Server: Marshall via Jackson JSON library 

4.) Transfer via JSON

5.) Client display via JQuery in the webpage (via the $ajax() call)
```

Is the process above correct? First HTML encoding then JavaScript encoding?

Do I have to JavaScript encode the content? As far as I can tell, Jackson will correctly encode the Content and Jquery is safe enough to parse even unsecure JavaScript content? So I could drop the JavaScript encoding, is this correct?

Thank you very much!
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you embedding?

If what you are embedding is plain text embedded in HTML embedded in JavaScript, e.g. `document.write("your text here")` then you need to HTML encode before you JS encode.

If what you are embedding is plain text embedded in JavaScript, embedded in HTML, e.g. `<button type=button onclick="alert('your text here')">` then you need to do it in the opposite order.

You can think about this as a type problem.  You have a string of type `string<plain_text>` and when you do something like `"<a ...>" + myPlainTextString + "</a>"` what you are doing is trying to append 3 strings of `string<html>` and to do that correctly you need to encode/cast the plain text string to `string<html>` so what you do is `"<a ...>" + htmlEncode(myPlainTextString + "</a>"`.

By this way of reasoning, 3 layers of embedding is just the same as 3 layers of type-casting.  Now if only I could convince language type system designers to build in checks for this kind of thing :)